# matplotlib text not clipped

Tags: python, matplotlib

When drawing text in `matplotlib` with `text()`, and then interactively panning the image, the resulting drawn text is not clipped to the data window.  This is counter to how plotting data or drawing text using `annotate()` works, and doesn't make intuitive sense as `text()` uses data window coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.text(0.5, 0.2, 'text')
ax.annotate('anno', (0.5, 0.3))

plt.draw()
```

Interactively pan the text out of the data window on all sides.  The `annotate()` drawn 'anno' is clipped when the reference point crosses the data window boundary, while the `text()` drawn 'text' is not.

I'm not sure if this behavior a feature or a bug, but sure seems like the latter, as this text interferes with axis labels, etc.  Using 1.2.1 with TkAgg backend.

An additional question would be how to properly clip all text from going outside the data window, not just when the reference coordinate does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This behavior can be controled by the kwarg `clip_on`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

txt = ax.text(0.5, 0.2, 'text')
anno = ax.annotate('anno', (0.5, 0.3))
txt_clip = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'text-clip', clip_on=True)

plt.draw()
```

`axes.text` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text).  There are arguments both for and against clipping the text to the data area.

There was a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1885) in mpl that made `txt.set_clip_on(True)` not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for responding, this solution does work (don't know why someone voted it down).  It is however curious that the original text object has clipping turned on.  `t1 = ax.text(0.5,0.2,'text'); t1.get_clip_on()` returns True.

Comment: Someone seems to be on a downvote spree from what I can tell.  If you didn't already, you should upvote and accept his answer.  It was still at -1 when I saw it.

Comment: @CNK Can you report that behavior (the incorrect result of `get_clip_on`) as a bug?

Comment: @tcaswell I will report it. Do you see this behavior as well?

Comment: @CNK yes, and cycling with `set_clip_on` seems to do nothing, but does what you expect if you explicitly pass `clip_on=True`

Comment: @tcaswell Bug seems to be that `get_clip_on` is set but `get_clip_bbox` is None.  When setting `get_clip_on=True` the bounding box is defined, and then it works.

Comment: @CNK I would post that as an answer (and accept yours instead of mine).